# calculate dfference per date with (my)sql

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation

I have a (mysql) table that looks like this:

```
|date      |status
|2017-07-10|done
|2017-07-10|new 
|2017-07-11|done
|2017-07-11|done 
|2017-07-12|done
|2017-07-12|done 
|2017-07-12|new
```

And now I want to have the count difference per date for status done (or all status) So on 2017-07-11 I get one, because there is one more with status done than on the day before, and so on.

```
|date      |cnt
|2017-07-11|1
|2017-07-12|0
```

I already have an SQL which gives me the result for ONE input date:

```
SELECT '2017-07-11' as d2,
       (SELECT count(*) as cnt 
          FROM table 
         WHERE status = 'done' 
           AND date > DATE_ADD(d2, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
           AND date < DATE_ADD(d2, INTERVAL 2 DAY)) - 
       (SELECT count(*) as cnt 
          FROM table 
         WHERE status = 'done' 
           AND date > d2 
           AND date < DATE_ADD(d2, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as cnt;
```

But this works only with a static date for d2, not a subquery. Can anyone help? I would also take a solution for postgres if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cur.dt,
       nxt.cnt - cur.cnt
  FROM (SELECT dt,
               COUNT(stat) cnt
          FROM tab
         WHERE stat = 'done'
         GROUP BY dt
       ) nxt
  JOIN 
       (SELECT (dt + 1) dt,
               COUNT(stat) cnt
          FROM tab
         WHERE stat = 'done'
         GROUP BY dt
       ) cur
    ON nxt.dt = cur.dt
```

Result

```
dt        nxt.cnt - cur.cnt
20170711  1
20170712  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Works. Also thx for the format fixing ;-) Tables in stackoverflow are a pain.

Comment: Here to help. :)